# How do I combine rows in groups and add the values of the other columns together?

Tags: crystal-reports

I have a Crystal Report that looks something like this:

```
Name         Kids         Dogs
John            1            0
John            1            1
Mary            2            1
Mary            0            1
Mary            1            1
William         1            2
William         1            0
```

I would like it to look like this:

```
Name    Kids   Dogs
John    2      1
Mary    3      3
William 2      2
```

Basically each row with the same "Name" is combined and the values of the other 2 columns are added together.  The end result is 1 row per name with sum of the other columns. I cannot seem to figure this one out. They are in a group by "Name" already.  Also this is using Crystal Reports 13 SP12.

Comment: Right Click on the field go to insert and click on the summary.

Comment: I did try that, but it always seems to give me a summary at the footer of the report, instead of combining the rows and giving me a sum of each column.  Is there a specific option I should be choosing?

Comment: Your fields are probably in details section. Move them to group footer. If it is not the solution, show a screenshot of your rpt design please.

Comment: That was it.  Thanks for your help.  Been fighting this one for awhile.